# Adding current location to Ruby on Rails app with photo_geoloader

Tags: html, cookies, geolocation, location, ruby-on-rails-5

So I've sent about 3 days researching geoip, geocoder, cookies, sessions, html5 and so forth.

I am trying to add a current location (as of the location when the user posts the photo in form).  The user will not change this data, I just want it to be automatically added to the post, and then added to the view of the post (currently i am using .time_ago for the timestamp of the post).  I can currently show in a map, but am lost as to adding it to the post.

I prefer to user HTML5 or

```
rails @lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng].split("|").
```

I just need it printed to the post of each user.

I have tried using Exifr gem to extract that data but it is not precise enough.  I am interested also in photo_geoloader gem yet there is little documentation.

So far i have created a model using "photo" as my model name.  Currently I am validating the uploaded image through my "post" model;

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable

  belongs_to :model
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy

  validates :model_id, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :caption, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 300 }

  has_attached_file :image,
                    styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.check_image_type}

  def check_image_type
    if is_image_type?
      {:medium => "640"}
    elsif is_video_type?
      {
          :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'flv'},
          :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :processors => [:transcoder]
    }
    else
      {}
    end
  end

  def is_image_type?
    image_content_type =~ %r(image)
  end

  def is_video_type?
    image_content_type =~ %r(video)
  end

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => [/\Aimage\/.*\Z/, /\Avideo\/.*\Z/, /\Aaudio\/.*\Z/]

  scope :of_followed_models, -> (following_models) { where model_id: following_models }
end
```

I have researched everything so I'm looking for a full process in rails 5 :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show us what you've tried so far to solve this problem (even if it's not working)? Generally speaking, we won't write your code for you, but we'll gladly help you debug what you've tried yourself. Edit your question (don't post it in comments because the formatting is impossible to read) and add all the relevant code-snippets you've got (eg where you show it on the map, your post model code).

Comment: If you haven't written a solution yet, I'd like you to try that now. Think about how you reckon you'd add it to your post if you had a magic wand and could make code do whatever you wanted... then write that and show us what you come up with. That way we can more easily see what you're trying to do, and can flesh out your solution with how it'd really work.